# .htaccess 301 redirection problem

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am having trouble writing a rule for following problem in .htaccess. Here is what I need.

WHEN URL IS THIS

```
www.mysite.com/cat/2011/subcat1/subcat2/product.htm?page=2
```

IT SHOULD 301 REDIRECT TO THIS

```
www.mysite.com/cat/2011/subcat1/subcat2/product/2.htm
```

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

----- EDITED AND TESTED ANSWER  ----------

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^cat/(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/product\.htm http://www.mysite.com/cat/$1/$2/$3/product/%1.htm? [R=301,L]
```

- RewriteRule matched only the url part, not the query string. So, RewriteCond is used to match query string.
- Please note, matches from the url are used as $N and match from the query string is used as %N
- There is a question mark placed in the end of the rewritten url. This prevents the original query string to be added to the new rewritten url.

For any number of subcats:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^cat/(\d+)/(.+)/product\.htm http://www.mysite.com/cat/$1/$2/product/%1.htm? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and then I will get back.

Comment: There was a problem in the previous answer. I have edited the answer and also tested to be working. It uses a RewriteCond and a ReWriteRule.

Comment: Ok I didn't use your method because I ran into a little problem as the number of subcat is not fixed. Sometime it could be 2, sometime 3 and sometime 4 or more (it is dynamic) so I have done it through PHP. I am not sure if there is a way to solve this problem through URL rewriting so I used PHP. But I have accepted your answer because I tested it with this current condition where there are only two subcat and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it using mod_rewrite for any number of subcats. I have edited the answer and added that